# Performance use of var, let or const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what are the differences in performance use of let, var and const in ES6.

Are there some benchmarks?

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75#.esmkpbg9b

This article clearly defines the difference between var , let and const